# How can I have multiple email accounts from different domains using Postfix?

Tags: centos, email, postfix, dovecot

I just made it through [**this**](http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-centos-7/#user) helpful article and successfully have my mail server set up with a single domain.

What I'm wondering now is how I can be able to add multiple email account for different domains.

To add a new email account currently, I would use the command:

```
useradd -m john -s /sbin/nologin
```

That would allow me to have an email that looks something like john@example.com.

What would I do if I wanted multiple domains? (like john@example2.com)

Thanks,
I'm still completely new to the world of VPS:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a `virtual_map` to map virtual users in your second domain to either real users on the server or to other addresses (similar to an alias).

e.g. in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` you would have:

```
virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

and in `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
example.com            VIRTUAL

john@example.com       john@myrealdomain.example.com
joe@example.com        joe@somewhere.else.example.com

# catch-all (optional and not recommended as it can act as a spam amplifier)
@example.com           john@myrealdomain.example.com


example2.com           VIRTUAL
john@example2.com      john@yet.another.example.com
fred@example2.com      fred@somewhere.else.again.example.com
@example2.com          someuser@myrealdomain.example.com
```

Remember to run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` after editing it.  And `postfix reload` after editing `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

See `man 5 virtual` for more details about the postfix virtual table format.

Comment: Awesome! How would the `useradd` command differ when adding a user for a specific email address?

Comment: They're virtual users - you wouldn't use useradd unless you needed to make a local user to deliver some or all of the virtual users' mail to.

Comment: Gotcha. So when I add this to my email client, would the password still be the same as the initial 'john' user that I created with the `useradd` command?

Comment: if that's the account you forward the mail to with the virtual table, then yes.